# How can I get data from a view using Azure and Mobile Services?

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services, sql-view

I'm trying to get the data from a view I created in the management portal of *Azure*. However, I'm not entirely sure of the syntax? If I use `client.getTable(viewName)` it doesn't work/doesn't find it. Additionally - AFAIK I know I'm meant to add the view as a table under my mobile services, but I get an **error 400** when I try this. I'm using android as my client application.

Any suggetions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Views in Mobile Services is not really stright forward. [This article does a good job on describing how to model a Mobile Service to support custom queries and views](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/32655170474/joinedtablesview/#.VC1MNekcTRk).

Yes, it involves creation of dummy tables that will stay empty. And would even call it dirty hacks to support a trivial things. But this is the reality for now (October the 2nd 2014). Hopefully that will change (soon).